# Given an array of integers arr, write a function that returns true if and only if the number of occurrences of each value in the array is unique

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
class Solution {
    public boolean uniqueOccurrences(int[] arr) {
        HashMap<Integer,Integer> hash = new HashMap<>();
        for(int i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
            if(hash.containsKey(arr[i])){
                hash.put(arr[i],hash.get(arr[i])+1);
            }else{
                hash.put(arr[i],1);
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
            for(int j = i+1;j<arr.length-1;j++){
                if(arr[i]!=arr[j] && hash.get(arr[i])==hash.get(arr[j])){
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
      return true;
    }
}
```

My code is actually failing for 1 test case which is [1,2].Can anybody tell me the reason and also how to optimize my code

Comment: *"**number of occurrences** of each value in the array **is unique**"* So [6, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2]` would be true, because the numbers 6, 4, and 2 **occurs** 1, 2, and 4 times, and the number 1, 2, and 4 are unique? --- And `[1, 3, 6]` is false, because the three numbers occurs 1, 1, and 1 times, so "occurrence 1" is not unique?

Comment: What result are you expecting for the input `[1, 2]`?

Comment: Change `j<arr.length-1` to `j<arr.length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `i` running from 0 (incl) to `length` (excl). So when `length` is 2, that gives you 0 and 1.

You have `j` running from `i+1` (incl) to `length-1` (excl).  That's an empty range for two inputs. `i+1` is at least 1, and `length-1` is also 1. Since the `j` loop doesn't run, you won't find any matches.

This would make more sense:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
```

That will actually check different pairs from your array.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is failing for input [1,2] is, size of your array is 2 and according to your code

```
for(int i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
        for(int j = i+1;j<arr.length-1;j++){
            if(arr[i]!=arr[j] && hash.get(arr[i])==hash.get(arr[j])){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

It will never enter inside 2nd for loop (i=0 so j=i+1 i.e j=1 and arr size = 2 so j<(2-1) condition failed also for i=1, j=i+1 i.e j=2, j<(2-1) condition failed).

try

```
for(int i = 0;i<arr.length-1;i++){
        for(int j = i+1;j<arr.length;j++){
            if(arr[i]!=arr[j] && hash.get(arr[i])==hash.get(arr[j])){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplified version of your code:

```
public static boolean uniqueOccurrences(int... arr) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int value : arr)
        map.merge(value, 1, Integer::sum);
    return map.size() == new HashSet<>(map.values()).size();
}
```

Or with a single statement using streams:

```
public static boolean uniqueOccurrences(int... arr) {
    return IntStream.of(arr).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())).values().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())).values().stream()
            .allMatch(i -> i == 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would replace that loop:

```
for(int i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
            for(int j = i+1;j<arr.length-1;j++){
                if(arr[i]!=arr[j] && hash.get(arr[i])==hash.get(arr[j])){
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
      return true;
```

with this, also more simplified. Since each item in a `Set` is unique and your keys are unique. If the two are equal then there is a 1-to-1 mapping.

```
Set<Integer> counts = new HashSet<>();
counts.addAll(hash.values());
return counts.size() == hash.keySet().size();
```